# How to order a Set in a specific order?

Tags: apex

I have a String Set named memtypes with these values in this order.

```
Associate Member
Committee Member
Honorary Member
Invitee
Member
Staff
```

I need to re-order it to

```
Members
Honorary Member
Associate Member
Committee Member
Staff
Invitee
```

How to do this?

Comment: If you want the order based on elements ordered and not alphabetical then use list. That way you will have more control on the elements that you add.

Comment: Yes but I can not have duplicates so I am using a set

Comment: Is each entry formatted like `member John Doe`, etc? If not, how are the strings formatted to denote the memtype? And, do you need them sorted alphabetically or just by type?

Comment: Each line above is a single entry. Nothing else is included. I need it by sorted like the second group. To get going I used a formula field to give a number per entry and did a SOQL to order it but I'd prefer a solution without depending on fields.

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no way to achieve what you are asking with Set. Set is an 'unordered' collection of elements. This means that Set is NOT ordered in one way or another, Set as a collection does not have any order at all. 
[link] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) [link] The iteration order of set elements is deterministic, so you can rely on the order being the same in each subsequent execution of the same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a wrapper class that implements [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm):

```
public class Wrapper implements Comparable {

    private static Map<String, Integer> ordering = {
            'Members' => 0,
            'Honorary Member' => 1,
            'Associate Member' => 2,
            'Committee Member' => 3,
            'Staff' => 4,
            'Invitee' => 5
            };

    public MySob__c sob {get; private set;}
    private Integer order;

    public Wrapper(MySob__c sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        this.order = ordering.get(sob.MemType__c);
        if (this.order == null) this.order = -1;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        Wrapper that = (Wrapper) o;
        return that.order - this.order;
    }
}
```

would allow you to use list's [sort](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm) method. A lot of lines of code for only 6 values though, especially when you have to wrap and unwrap the values. (I'm assuming you want to order an SObject that has a memtype field here.)

Using a field and SOQL as you mention in your comment seems like a cleaner way to go.